# Convert to csv file with same name using AWK command

Tags: linux, awk, csv

I'm using this command to process text files and my goal is to save my output in CSV format.

```
awk -f test.awk /FILES/detail-1019:01 > detail-1019_01.csv
```

But problem is, I have many files and I don't want to run my processing command on each file individually. So how should i ran my processing command and save each files in CSV format in one go ?

Input file names:

```
detail-1019:17
detail-1019:18
detail-1019:19
detail-1019:20
detail-1019:21
detail-1019:22
```

My desired output file name:

```
detail-1019_17.csv
detail-1019_18.csv
detail-1019_19.csv
detail-1019_20.csv
detail-1019_21.csv
detail-1019_22.csv
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do

```
for f in /FILES/detail*; do awk -f test.awk $f > $(echo $f | sed -e 's/^\/FILES\///' -e 's/:/_/').csv; done
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Your command worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

There are two main ways to go about this.

1. Use a shell loop in which you call your `awk` code and redirect the output to a name that is derived from the current input file, or
2. Call `awk` once with *all* files as arguments, and do the output to an appropriately named file inside your `awk` script.  Note that this would only be possible if you have fewer than thousands of files.

I will not touch upon the second of these two as we can't see your `awk` code and therefore can't suggest what needs to be changed in it (if you're using `NR`, for example, this may possibly have to change to using `FNR`, and there may be other changes needed too).

---

Using a shell loop:

```bsh
for pathname in /FILES/detail-*:??; do
    name=${pathname##*/}
    awk -f script.awk "$pathname" >"${name%:??}_${name##*:}.csv"
done
```

The three parameter substitutions used here:

1. `${pathname##*/}`, removes the directory path from the pathname and leaves just the filename portion of the string.
2. `${name%:??}`, removes the trailing `:` character and the two characters after that from the filename in `name`.  This bit is then concatenated with an underscore and with ...
3. `${name##*:}.csv`, removes everything up to the `:` at the end of the filename and adds a `.csv` filename suffix at the end.

The 2nd and 3rd substitutions are used to replace the `:` at the end of the filename with `_` to create the output filename.